# Efficient string slicing in AWK

Tags: awk, text, replace

I'd like to use AWK for replacing a set of dynamic patterns in an input file that looks like this:

```
one ^var^ two
^var^ three ^var^
four five six
seven eight ^var^
```

Here's the (relatively) idiomatic approach, that processes input line-by-line:

```
BEGIN {
  FS = ""
  vars["var"] = "yay!"
}

{
  while (match($0, /\^[[:alnum:]_]+\^/)) {
    var = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
    $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) vars[var] substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  print
}
```

In this case, there's a single variable `^var^` that gets replaced by `yay!`, but there can be many different ones and the mapping is loaded dynamically.

It is reasonably fast on all AWK implementations that I've tried, with the slowest (GoAWK) taking roughly 320ms to process a 4.9MiB test file with the example input concatenated 1000 times.

However, I'd like to be able to handle very long lines, or have newlines inside `^` delimiters, so here's an approach that reads whole input at once and then prints slices of it while traversing:

```
BEGIN {
  RS = "\x1"
  FS = ""
  vars["var"] = "yay!"
}

{
    while (match($0, /\^[[:alnum:]_]+\^/)) {
        printf "%s%s", substr($0, 1, RSTART-1), vars[substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)]
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    printf "%s", $0
}
```

However, it is significantly slower. Only GoAWK is able to process the same file in about 290ms. MAWK takes 48 seconds, NAWK - ~3 minutes, and GAWK is veeery slow - I didn't wait for it to finish, but it's over 10 minutes.

That is probably expected, considering how inefficient is `$0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)` line. I wonder how GoAWK makes it so fast - maybe some copy-on-write magic?

Anyway, I'd like to know if there's a (ideally portable) way to do this fast in GAWK and/or MAWK. I know that the same can be achieved with a Perl one-liner, or a Python couple-liner, but I need to do it in AWK :)

Edit, some clarifications:

- Main issue is while/match performance. I said about multiline patterns just as an example to demonstrate usefulness of the "read everything at once, then replace" approach. But my main concern is huge lines (usually a big file with a single line and no useful delimiter).
- I don't expect the pattern delimiter character to show up in data, so I'll experiment with setting FS to `^`, maybe that'll be enough. But I'd prefer to use match, if possible, so that if `^` does show up in data I can tweak the regex and ignore it.

Comment: might help if you could provide a bit more in terms of sample inputs and replacements, specifically to address the variations you mention; will you be doing one replacement at a time or many? how are the replacement(s) to be loaded into `awk` ... `-v variable="value"` or from file? if loading from file, how do you plan to distinguish between `\n` as part of the replacement string vs normal line delimiter? do you have to worry about your target delimiter (`^`) showing up in normal data (either in the source or replacements)?

Comment: @Discussion : `while (match($0, /\^[[:alnum:]_]+\^/))` why are even you complaining about my `FS` being restrictive when this regex of yours doesn't even allow dashes commas math operators ampersands periods apostrophes or any form of spaces in between, whether it's space `\x20` tab `CR` `newline/LF` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's question seems to cover two separate issues:

- performance issue with current `while/match()` loop
- replacing multi-line patterns (though we're given no examples)

Addressing the current performance issue ...

Setup:

```
$ cat sample.base
one ^var^ two
^var^ three ^var^
four five six
seven eight ^var^
nine ^not var^ ten           # should not be replaced
```

Create a 6.6 MB file:

```
awk '
    { lines[FNR]=$0 }
END { for (i=1;i<=80000;i++)
          for (j in lines)
              print lines[j]
    }
' sample.base > sample.5M
```

Running OP's current `awk` code against this 6.6 MB file I noticed:

- when printing to stdout it ran for ~10 seconds before I started to see results dumped to the console; killed after 20 seconds
- when printing to file ... killed after 30 seconds with nothing showing up in the output file

**NOTE:** I'm running `GNU awk 5.1.1` in a `cygwin` env.

Making some modifications to OP's current `awk` script:

- replace the `while/match()` loop with a `for` loop that steps through a list of `^`-delimited fields
- add a check for our pattern match in the `vars[]` array

Resulting code:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS = "\x1"
        FS = "^"                                 # set field delimiter to "^"
        vars["var"] = "yay!"
      }
      { for (i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2) {                  # step through even numbered fields
            if ($i in vars)                      # do we have a replacement for this field?
               printf "%s%s", $(i-1), vars[$i]
            else 
               printf "%s%s", $(i-1), FS $i FS   # make sure we re-add the field delimiter
        }
        printf "%s\n", $(i+1)
      }
' sample.5M > sample.out
```

**NOTE:** this assumes the `^` character is *only* used as a delimiter and does *not* show up as part of normal data

Running several invocations of `time awk '....'` the average worked out to ~ 540 ms (0.54 secs).

The result:

```
$ head sample.out
one yay! two
yay! three yay!
four five six
seven eight yay!
nine ^not var^ ten           # was not replaced
one yay! two
yay! three yay!
four five six
seven eight yay!
nine ^not var^ ten           # was not replaced
```

---

As for the 2nd half of OP's question - re: replacing multi-line patterns - I'd recommend that be split out into a separate question, complete with sample inputs/outputs demonstrating OP's requirement ...

Comment: I tried to clarify a couple things in the OP. But this approach looks pretty good, I'll experiment with it. Thank you!

Comment: @markp-fuso : if u just wanna print a file out 80,000 times, just set `FS = RS = "^$"` in `BEGIN { }` section, read it in all at once, then in `END { }` section, set `OFS = $0`, set `NF = 80000`, blank out `ORS = ""`, then print it all at once

Answer (score 0):

You might exploit GNU `AWK`'s `RS` and `RT` to support multi-line variable, following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
one two ^var
1^
three ^var
2^
four five six
seven eight ^var
3^
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\^var\n[0-9]+\\^";arr["^var\n1^"]="uno";arr["^var\n2^"]="dos";arr["^var\n3^"]="tres"}{printf "%s%s",$0,(RT in arr)?arr[RT]:RT}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
one two uno
three dos
four five six
seven eight tres
```

Explanation: `RS` is row separator, `RT` is row terminator, for each line-terminator pair I do look into array `arr` and if present in array I use corresponding value.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo '1  one ^bar^ two
        2  ^foo^ three ^foo^
        3  four five six
        4  seven eight ^bar^ ^bar^'      | 

  gtee >( gpaste - | gcat - | ecp >&2; ) |
```

|

```
 1  one ^bar^ two
 2  ^foo^ three ^foo^
 3  four five six
 4  seven eight ^bar^ ^bar^
```

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { ORS =     ""; RS = "^$"            
>               OFS = "yay!"; FS = "[\\^]foo[\\^]" 
>
>      } gsub(/\^bar\^/, "wow!", $!(NF = NF))'
> ```

```
 1  one wow! two
 2  yay! three yay!
 3  four five six
 4  seven eight wow! wow!
```

**UPDATE 2** :

if you're very certain the `^` things always come in pairs, and there must be some stuff in between,

and wanna gamble, then do

> ```
> gawk NF=NF FS='\\^[^^]+\\^' OFS='yay!' RS='^$' ORS=
> mawk   ……    FS='\^[^^]+\^'   ……   ……   ……    ……
> ```

**UPDATE 1** : showcasing newlines in between (borrowsing **Fravadona's** example)

```
 1  one ^v a r^ two
 2  ^v
 3  a
 4  r^ three ^v a r^
 5  four five six
 6  seven eight ^v
 7  a
 8  r^
```

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='[\^]v[^^]*a[^^]*r[\^]' OFS='yay!' RS='^$' ORS=
> ```

```
 1  one yay! two
 2  yay! three yay!
 3  four five six
 4  seven eight yay!
```

*for `gawk` or `nawk`, double the backslash in `FS`*

#############################################################

don't make life more complicated than need be :

```
 1  one ^var^ two
 2  ^var^ three ^var^
 3  four five six
 4  seven eight ^var^
```

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='\\^var\\^' OFS='yay!'
> ```

```
 1  one yay! two
 2  yay! three yay!
 3  four five six
 4  seven eight yay!
```

tested and confirmed working on `gawk 5.2.1`, `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.9.9.6`, and `nawk 2020-08-16`

***0.442 secs*** to finish replacing `2^21` input rows spanning `32.0 MB` should be fast enough for most needs

```
fgc; ( time ( echo "${input_data}" | 

 mawk2 'BEGIN {  FS =  RS = "^$"
                OFS = ORS = ""
        } 
        gsub(".",$_) + gsub(".",($_)($_))' | LC_ALL=C shuf ) | 

pvE0 | mawk2 NF=NF FS='\\^var\\^' OFS='yay!' | pvE9 ) | wc5 

      in0: 32.0MiB 0:00:00 [75.9MiB/s] [75.9MiB/s] [  <=> ]
     out9: 28.2MiB 0:00:00 [82.9MiB/s] [70.5MiB/s] [ <=>  ]

( echo "${input_data}" | mawk2  | LC_ALL=C shuf; )

         0.30s user 0.03s system 73% cpu 0.442 total

pvE 0.1 in0  

         0.01s user 0.02s system 6% cpu 0.441 total

mawk2 NF=NF FS='\\^var\\^' OFS='yay!'  

        0.35s user 0.01s system 82% cpu 0.440 total

rows = 2097152. | UTF8 chars = 31457280. | bytes = 31457280.
```

`4 MB` input isnt' that big for `awk`. if you're concerned about newlines between the markers, read the entire file into a single row's `$0`, then modify `FS` there to account for those,

Comment: I mentioned in the OP that patterns are dynamic - there can be any word between `^`s. And the replacements (`vars` array) are also loaded dynamically, I just didn't want to complicate the examples with the implementation. So setting OFS to some value won't help, as replacement should be the dynamic result result of evaluating `vars["text_inside_pattern"]`.

Comment: @Discussian : so you don't know how to adapt these solutions to a broader problem and expect us to do your homework for you ?

Comment: They can't be adapted. OFS is a static string. How could your solution possibly work if there are even two patterns, like `^foo^` and `^bar^`? I clearly stated in the OP that there can be many different patterns in the input and they have to be handled dynamically. Yes, I didn't include an example of such case so I don't blame you for missing it, but I already pointed it out in the first comment to your solution. Sorry, but your solution doesn't handle dynamic substitutions and can't be adapted to do it. But the accepted solution can, so that's what I'm using, with some modifications.

Comment: @Discussian :  `FS='[\^](f[^^]*o[^^]*o|b[^^]*a[^^]*r)[\^]'` . `OFS` is static here, and you can't figure out how to leverage `FS` together with `gsub()` ?

Comment: And how would you replace `^foo^` with `yay!` and `^bar^` with `wow!` with this approach? OFS is a static string, so you can't.

Comment: @Discussian : because it's soooooooooo difficult - see my updated answer